# How can I display A ViewBag using information from my database and using .include()?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET/EntityFramework and I have created a simple Bank app. The problem I am having is that I can't get the balance to display.
here is the key part that I need to use in my model:

```
        public double Balance
    {
        get { return Transactions.Sum(transaction => transaction.Amount); }
    }
```

and here is the key part in my controller that I need to use:

```
        [HttpPost("/money")]
    public IActionResult Money(Transaction trans)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.balance = dbContext.Transactions
                .Include(t => t.Amount);
            dbContext.Transactions.Add(trans);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var user = loggedInUser;
        ViewBag.User = user;
        ViewBag.Transactions = dbContext.Transactions
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedAt)
            .Where(t => t.UserId == loggedInUser.UserId);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

and here is my View where I am trying to get the balance using ViewBag:

```
<p>Current balance: @ViewBag.User.Balance</p>
```

Im assuming the problem has something to do with this:

```
ViewBag.balance = dbContext.Transactions
                .Include(t => t.Amount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you can get value from `dbContext.Transactions.Include(t => t.Amount);`.

Second, you set  `ViewBag.balance = ...`, so in your view. You can get it by `<p>Current balance: @ViewBag.balance</p>`.

**Tips:**

If you want get value from `User` model, you need add `@model User`, then you can use something like `@Model.Balance` to get balance.

For more details, you can refer official doc:

[Part 4, add a model to an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)